# Is there a way to compare two strings where select and value are different types?

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problems to compare two strings in jQuery:

```
var option = "";
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
   option += "<option ";
   if(selected == value) {
      option += "selected";
   }
   option += ">" + value + "</option>";
});
```

selected and value are the same strings.

Is there an another way to compare two strings or could it be, that selected and value are different types?

Comment: Without your html is hard to tell but try with `if(selected === value)`, that will make sure they're the same type.

Comment: where's "selected" coming from...?

Comment: How do you know they are the same strings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to consider this:

> The == operator compares two values and returns true if the values on
>   both sides are equal to one another. If the two values have different
>   data types (for example, if one is a number and the other is a text
>   string) then they are both converted to the same type before the
>   comparison takes place. JavaScript will convert whichever of the two
>   types can be converted to the other type without having to change the
>   value contained in the variable (for example, converting a number to a
>   text string).
>
> The === operator does the same thing with one minor difference. This
>   operator does not convert data from one type to another. It only
>   returns true when the variables being compared are both of the same
>   type and contain the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
selected.substring(0,4)==value.substring(0,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `localeCompare` method?

```
if(selected.localeCompare(value) === 0) {
  . . . 
}
```

The method will **return**:

- **0:** whenever the strings are equal
- **-1:** if *selected* is smaller than *value*
- **1:** if *selected* is bigger than *value*